# How to create a software loading window with TKinter?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, load, tkinter-layout

With Tkinter how can i create a small software loading window? A window whose hard loading for example 7 seconds and then automatically open the software, for example the home.py file.

How can I open another window automatically after 7 seconds?  Thanks

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
import tkinter as tk
import time

root =  Tk()
root.title("load")
root.geometry("300x300")
root.state("normal")

lbl = Label(root, text="EXAMPLE", font=("Calibri 15 bold"))
lbl(x=40, y=40)


def wait_and_go():
    time.sleep(7)
```

Comment: I suggest you create a [`ttk.Progressbar`](https://anzeljg.github.io/rin2/book2/2405/docs/tkinter/ttk-Progressbar.html) and use the universal widget [`after()`](https://anzeljg.github.io/rin2/book2/2405/docs/tkinter/universal.html) method to update it for as long a needed.

Comment: @Zankaclowski do you mean a loading animation for 7 seconds?

Comment: tkinter need to run `mainloop` to work - it creates window, gets mouse/key events from system, sends them to widgets, and redraws widgets in window, and it do it in `loop`. if you use `sleep()` then this `loop` can't work and you can't see anything or it is frozen. You have to use `after(7000, func)` to run `func()` after 7 seconds and this `func()` should do what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`tkinter` (similar to all other GUIs in Python and other languages) needs to run special `loop` to work. This loop creates window, gets mouse/key events from system, sends them to widgets, and redraws widgets in window, and it do it again and again. And you need `root.mainloop()` for this.

If you use `sleep()` then this `loop` can't work and you can't see anything or it is frozen. But `tkinter` can use `root.after(7000, func)` to run `func()` after 7 seconds and this `func()` should do what you want.

```
import tkinter as tk  # PEP8: `import *` is not preferred

# --- function ---

def func():
    print('Now I can run something else')
    #root.destroy()
    
# --- main ---

root = tk.Tk()

lbl = tk.Label(root, text="EXAMPLE")
lbl.pack(padx=50, pady=50)  # padx=(50,0), pady=(50,50)

root.after(7000, func)  # function's name without `()`

root.mainloop()
```

---

You can also use `after()` to run again and again function which can change text in label and countdown time.

```
import tkinter as tk  # PEP8: `import *` is not preferred

# --- function ---

def func():
    print('Now I can run something else')
    root.destroy()  # close window

def update_label():
    global counter  # inform function to assign new value to external/global variable
    
    counter -= 1
    
    lbl['text'] = f'COUNTDOWN: {counter} s'
    
    if counter > 0:
        root.after(1000, update_label)
    
# --- main ---

counter = 7  # this is global variable 

root = tk.Tk()

lbl = tk.Label(root, text=f'COUNTDOWN: {counter} s')
lbl.pack(padx=50, pady=50)  # padx=(50,0), pady=(50,50)

root.after(7000, func)  # function's name without `()`

root.after(1000, update_label)  # function's name without `()`
#update_label()

root.mainloop()
```

---

**EDIT:**

Example with `ttk.Progressbar`.

```
import tkinter as tk  # PEP8: `import *` is not preferred
import tkinter.ttk as ttk

# --- function ---

def func():
    print('Now I can run something else')
    root.destroy()  # close window
    
# --- main ---

root = tk.Tk()

pb = ttk.Progressbar(root, maximum=7.001)
pb.pack(padx=50, pady=50)  # padx=(50,0), pady=(50,50)
pb.start(1000)  # start and change every 1000ms
#pb.step(-1)    # move back one step (to 0) because `start()` moves automatically to `1`

root.after(7000, func)  # function's name without `()`

root.mainloop()
```